# Question about EnviromentFile config setting for Gunicorn and Django production, do I need to use it?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a Django app in production, using gunicorn for help. I have a question about the setting `EnviromentFile`, should I refence the venv path for my project? Is it mandatory? The reason why I'm not adding it in my service file, is because I'm not serving any variables through the env.

`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`  :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/alpha/project
ExecStart=/home/user/alpha/project/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Do I still need to add, `EnviromentFile`,to my file above? And if I do, is referencing the activation needed? Like  so: `EnviromentFile=PATH/TO/venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: You're doing this `/home/user/alpha/project/venv/bin/gunicorn` it _should_ pick up the `python` bin inside the same folder. Whats the error you're seeing?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, I'm not getting any error, I just saw a lot of other service files stating an `EnviromentFile`. Was wondering if I should do the same, but judging from your response it seems like I can just ignore that configuration setting?

Comment: Yup. What you have _should_ work, and it's very clean.